# "Current provider does not support transactions", Classic ASP and Informix DB

Tags: asp-classic, informix

I have a classic ASP application which uses an Informix database to fetch data. We are getting "Current provider does not support transactions" on Con.BeginTrans statement. What does this mean and how can we fix it?

Comment: it would help to know (or see) what kind of connection string you're using. also, if you're using ODBC, make sure you're running in 32-bit mode, and not 64 bit mode, as classic asp will not support 64 bit mode.

Comment: One other important point to check is whether the Informix database you're connecting to is 'logged' or 'unlogged'. There are three sub-types of logged, but that doesn't matter as much as logged vs unlogged.  Unlogged Informix databases don't have a transaction log and therefore do not support transactions. If the database was created without a log (someone didn't specify `CREATE DATABASE xyz WITH LOG` or similar), then you are stuck if the client code requires transactions. You can add logging to a database, but that isn't something that should be done idly _if_ the database is in production.

Comment: It would also help to know which version of Informix you are using — for the server in particular, but also the client software too.  Presumably, the platform is Windows; it might be relevant to identify which version of Windows, though.